# League of Legends won't open. I get an error that refers to a PVP.net Patcher Kernel. How do I fix it?

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

When I try to open League of Legends in Windows 7 I am notified that PVP.net Patcher Kernel has stopped working and that Windows hasn't found a solution, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling the game? Or Repairing the install?

This is a bit of a common error.

Also, when you ran the install, did you run it as an administrator?

You can also try these steps:

> 1. Close out your game/patcher, hit ctrl+alt+delete and make sure all instances of LoL.Launcher are gone, then restart the patcher process and let it sit.
> 2. Go to your Riot Games/RADS/System folder under your default install path, and run the rads_user_kernel.exe file, then try starting your patcher.
> 3. See this article, http://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/234188-changing-to-public-dns-servers
> 4. Replace /RADS/system/rads_user_kernel.exe with this file, http://l3cdn.riotgames.com/releases/live/system/rads_user_kernel.exe
> 5. Try installing Microsoft Dot NET Framework 4.0, http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17851 and 3.5, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/e...displaylang=en

Source: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1319346

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking and running as administrator works most of the time. Try it first.